# how to use the bash variable in single quotes

Tags: bash

I am having bash code like below

```
'payload={"text": "failure with ${VAR} failed for"}'
```

but the variable is not resolving to actual value
Please don't put negative as I don't have that much experience in Bash so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables don't expand in single quotes, which means that you simply have to ensure that they are not single-quoted. You have several possibilities, for instance:

```
'payload={"text": "failure with '"${VAR}"' failed for"}'
```

or

```
"payload={\"text\": \"failure with ${VAR} failed for\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate variables directly.

```
'payload={"text": "failure with '${VAR}' failed for"}'
```

Comment: This leaves `${VAR}` unquoted, which can cause trouble if it contains any whitespace or some other funny characters. You really want to keep your variable references in double-quotes to avoid this.

Comment: Space or special character variables can be quoted with double quotes when defining to avoid errors. Of course, your suggestion is good, thank you!

Comment: Quoting when the variable is defined (or embedding quotes or escapes in the variable's value) doesn't prevent it from being word-split when it's used; you really need to double-quote when using the variable to prevent weird parsing.